# Graph Theory and Soccer

Tags: python, data-analysis, graph-theory

After dividing the soccer field into 18 zones, I identified some events, in which I got their respective origin and destination zones. At the end of this data collection, I have a spreadsheet with 3 columns. In the first I have information from source zones, in the second the destination zones. The third column consists of the number of occurrence of interactions between the zones. For example, the interaction between zones 8 -17 occurred 30 times, while the interaction between zones 7 - 10 occurred only 3. With this information, I was able to use the following code to represent these interactions:

Now, I would like to know which metrics I could use, from graph theory, to check the efficiency of these interactions?

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm as cm

# Filtrar as linhas do DataFrame onde o valor da coluna 'tipo' é igual a 'isolada'
df_tipo_combinada = df_tipo_zona[df_tipo_zona['tipo'] == 'Combinada']

# Criar um objeto do tipo DiGraph (grafo direcionado)
grafo_c = nx.DiGraph()

# Adicionar os nós ao grafo
nodos = list(df_tipo_combinada['zona_origem'].unique()) +         list(df_tipo_combinada['zona_destino'].unique())
grafo_c.add_nodes_from(nodos)

# Adicionar as arestas ao grafo
for index, row in df_tipo_combinada.iterrows():
origem = row['zona_origem']
destino = row['zona_destino']
contagem = row['contagem']
grafo_c.add_edge(origem, destino, weight=contagem)

# Definir a posição dos nós no campo de futebol
pos = {
1: (0, 2),    2: (0, 1),    3: (0, 0),
4: (1, 2),    5: (1, 1),    6: (1, 0),
7: (2, 2),    8: (2, 1),    9: (2, 0),
10: (3, 2),   11: (3, 1),    12: (3, 0),
13: (4, 2),   14: (4, 1),    15: (4, 0),
16: (5, 2),   17: (5, 1),    18: (5, 0)
}

# Definir o tamanho dos nós de acordo com a contagem de interações
node_sizes = [50 * grafo_c.degree[node] for node in grafo_c.nodes()]

# Definir a cor dos nós de acordo com a contagem de interações
node_colors = [grafo_c.degree[node] for node in grafo_c.nodes()]
node_colors_normalized = [float(x) / max(node_colors) for x in node_colors]
node_colors_scaled = cm.summer(node_colors_normalized)

# Definir a espessura das setas de acordo com a contagem de interações
edge_widths = [0.1 * grafo_c[u][v]['weight'] for u, v in grafo_c.edges()]

# Desenhar o grafo
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(grafo_c, pos, node_color=node_colors_scaled, node_size=node_sizes)
nx.draw_networkx_edges(grafo_c, pos, width=edge_widths, arrowsize=10)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(grafo_c, pos, font_size=10)
plt.title('Grafo de interações entre zonas (Tipo: Combinada)')

# Criar a barra de cores
sm = ScalarMappable(cmap=cm.summer)
sm.set_array(node_colors)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sm, ax=plt.gca(), orientation='horizontal', pad=0.03)

# Remover os números da legenda
cbar.ax.set_xticklabels([])

# Adicionar "< ocorrência" à extrema esquerda da legenda
cbar.ax.text(2.2, 0.5, "< ocorrência", ha='left', va='center')

# Adicionar "> ocorrência" à extrema direita da legenda
cbar.ax.text(13.8, 0.5, "> ocorrência", ha='right', va='center')

# Posicionar a legenda abaixo do gráfico
cbar.ax.xaxis.set_label_position('bottom')
cbar.ax.xaxis.tick_bottom()

# Mostrar o grafo com a legenda
plt.show()`
```

Comment: "check the efficiency of these interactions" How do you define efficiency?